# How to combine same-named worksheets on different workbooks to a new workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, copy, worksheet

I want to combine same-named worksheets on different workbooks in a folder to a new workbook.

I would like to have the worksheets named by the name of the file from which they were copied.

```vb
Sub collectionOfSheets()

    Dim strF As String, strP As String
    strP = "path to source files folder"                                          
    strF = Dir(strP & "\*.xlsx")

    Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:="filename of destination workbook"
  
    Do While strF <> vbNullString
      Workbooks.Open (strP & "\" & strF)
      ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Workbooks("filename of destination workbook").Sheets(1)
      Workbooks("filename of destination workbook").Sheets(1).Name = "strF"
      Workbooks("filename of destination workbook").Save
      strF = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub collectionOfSheets()

    Dim strF As String, strP As String
    Dim wbNew As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add()  'for collecting the sheets
    wbNew.SaveAs Filename:="filename of destination workbook"
    
    strP = "path to source files folder"
    strF = Dir(strP & "\*.xlsx")

    Do While strF <> vbNullString
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strP & "\" & strF)
        wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=wbNew.Sheets(1)
        wbNew.Sheets(1).Name = Replace(strF, ".xlsx", "") 'without extension
        wbNew.Save
        wb.Close False 'close ?
        strF = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

Using workbook variables makes it easier to manage the process...

Comment: Thanks a million dear Tim for your response. I am getting an error that says that the name is invalid with three possibilities enumerated 1. name contains>31 characters? 2. name contains \ / ? * 3. name is blank. I just counted the name length and it is indeed more than 31 letters. i need a middle part of the name, so will try to look up and figure how to do that. thank you again!

Comment: Depending on what part of the name you need, you can likely use `Mid()` or `Split()` to extract it.  If you can post more detail I will add that to my answer.